# Картошка фри: как правильно писать?

Tags: орфография

Меня заклинило на таким простом выражении, как "картошка фри". Как правильно его нужно писать: "картошка-фри" или "картошка "фри"? Или просто "картошка фри". Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно *картофель фри*. Фри - неизменяемое прилагательное, обозначающее способ приготовления.

Сравните с грилем: овощи гриль (приготовленные на гриле) и решетка-гриль (здесь гриль - существительное, обозначающее устройство для приготовления).

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: картошка фри. Фри - неизменяемое слово, может, как и наречие, играть роль несогласованного определения.

Но: курица-гриль. Гриль - существительное и в препозиции является приложением и пишется через дефис.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ
Однако, нет. Словарь, который мне попался, по-видимому. устарел. Тогда можно обсудить правильность новой орфографии.

1. «Курица гриль» – неплохой вариант письма,  ничем не хуже, чем  «картофель фри».  Но чтобы орфография соответствовала правилам, надо правильно указывать значение слова в ТОЛКОВЫХ СЛОВАРЯХ. «Фри, гриль» – это неизменяемые слова со значением  «приготовленные жарением», фактически ГРАММАТИЧЕСКИЕ НАРЕЧИЯ.

Однако в Грамоте.ру   неизменяемость слова не отмечена, там «гриль»  является  первой частью сложных слов с дефисным написанием, да и редко в каком словаре это неизменяемость присутствует.
Но у слова «гриль» есть еще одно значение – устройство для жарения мяса, рыбы, овощей на решетках и вертелах, и в этом случае мы имеем существительное м.рода.

1. Только после наведения порядка в толковых словарях МОЖНО ОБЪЯСНИТЬ написание этого слова в различных сочетаниях, например:

А) Курица  гриль – несогласованное определение (в нормальной позиции), выраженное неизм. словом «гриль».

Б) Гриль-курица, гриль-бар, гриль-решетка, гриль-барбекю, гриль-печь – сущ. м.р «гриль»  является приложением в препозиции, но пишется через дефис, так как НЕ СКЛОНЯЕТСЯ.

В) Решетка-гриль, печь-гриль – здесь приложение в постпозиции, всегда дефисное написание.

Г) А можно написать «гриль бар», например: «Список лучших гриль баров в Москве»? Пока это еще нелегитимная, но достаточно активная орфография «английского типа»: несклоняемое приложение + определение.

Д) А «домик гриль»?  Так лучше не писать. Несклоняемое слово «гриль» сюда не подходит, а приложение в постпозиции в обозримом будущем, скорее всего, будет писаться через дефис

Comment: http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search_answer/?s=%E3%F0%E8%EB%FC

Пишутся раздельно названия блюд, приготовленных на гриле: курица гриль, овощи гриль, цыпленок гриль. Однако через дефис пишутся названия кухонных приспособлений, совмещающих в себе гриль и что-то еще: духовка-гриль, печь-гриль.
Такое же написание зафиксировано в Орфографическом словаре: куры гриль.